# Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ have a supremum $x$. Show that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ that converges to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I understand how to prove this using the approximation property of the supremum and invoking the squeeze theorem of limits. However, upon reading answers for similar questions, I think there's a more direct way of proving this without using the squeeze theorem. I'm having trouble understanding the logic though. I was wondering if I could receive some guidance. Here is what I have so far:

Since $x$ is the least upper bound of $S$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can pick an $x_n \in S$ such that $x_n > x - \frac{1}{n}$. Since $x$ is an upper bound of $S$, $x \geq x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore we have $x \geq x_n > x-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How do I go from here to showing that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ using the definition of convergence (without using squeeze theorem)?

Comment: Erm, just as in the proof of the squeeze theorem?

Comment: I see now how the two approaches are related. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every fixed $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ (this follows by the Archimedean property). Thus, for all $n\geq N$, $|x_{n}-x|=x-x_{n}<x-(x-\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer explicitly mentioned the definition of convergence so it was easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

From $x\ge x_n>x-1/n$ we have $|x-x_n|=x-x_n<1/n$, for every $n$.

Comment: Makes sense, but in order to show convergence wouldn't we have to show that there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the definition of convergence for all $n \geq N$?

Comment: Due to the Archimedian property (as in ervx's post), it's enough to show $|x-x_n|<1/n$ for every $n$.